# Calling controller function from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this controller attached to a div:

```
.controller('ShowInverterConnectController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

....

}])
```

I would like to use the $location argument of it.

I am currently doing this:

```
angular.element('.ng-scope').scope().$apply(function() {
    console.log('test:', angular.element('.ng-scope').scope().$location);
});
```

But $location is coming out undefined, is there anyway to use $location?

Thanks

Comment: are you using angular.element.... within the controller or out of controller?

Comment: Thanks @BhojendraNepal its from out of the controller, dfsq's solution below worked great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with Angular service outside of the app, but I assume you have a good reason, because in many cases this will be considered bad practice. Anyway.

[`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) is not a property of the scope, so you can't get it like you are trying. However you can use [`$injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) service to retrieve other services like `$location`:

```
angular.element('.ng-scope').scope().$apply(function() {
    console.log('test:', angular.element('.ng-scope').injector().get('$location'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a fast reply! We have a jquery mobile app we're converting to angularjs for speed but a huge bulk of it cannot be converted within reasonable time, so we are forced to use a mix for this release. Thanks very much.

Comment: Would getting `$location` via `injector()` be the preferred way over setting a variable within the controller? Like to `$scope.loc = $location` and then go `angular.element('.ng-scope').loc`?

Comment: I would go with $injector, so you don't pollute scope with properties that are not needed to business logic.

Comment: Thank you @dfsq this is some really interesting learning. I will plus your replies asoon as I get 15 rep. Thanks very much also for the fast replies!